# OutOfMemory when removing rows > 500000 EntityFramework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, out-of-memory

## What I've got:

I have a large list of addresses(ip addr) > millions

## What I'm trying to do:

Remove 500k addresses efficiently through EntityFramework

## My Problem:

Right now, I'm splitting into lists of 10000 addresses and using RemoveRange(ListOfaddresses)

```
if (addresses.Count() > 10000)
{
    var addressChunkList = extension.BreakIntoChunks<Address>(addresses.ToList(), 10000);
    foreach (var chunk in addressChunkList)
    {
        db.Address.RemoveRange(chunk);
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an `OutOfMemoryException` which must mean that it's not freeing resources even though I'm splitting my addresses into separate lists.

What can I do to not get the OutOfMemoryException and still remove large quantities of addresses within reasonable time?

Comment: Just occurred to me, that my exception is thrown when I'm trying to SaveChanges();

Comment: use even smaller chunks? Try it with 5000, 2500, 1250 .... 1 up until the point that the Exception disappears?

Comment: It has no problem when the address space is near 100000 addresses even without splitting into smaller chunks

Comment: Is it maybe easier to just write the SQL to do this? I think you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I have needed to do something similar I have turned to the following plugin (I am not associated).

https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

This allows you to do bulk deletes using Entity Framework without having to select and load the entity into the memory first which of course is more efficient.

Example from the website:

```
context.Users.Delete(u => u.FirstName == "firstname");
```

Comment: This is actually faster then creating the rows - just tested with 1million rows, took about 4 seconds to create and about 3 seconds to delete +1

Comment: I agree that the solution needs to take into account the best tool for the job., but this is a very interesting project. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

So? WHere did you get the idea EF is an ETL / bulk data manipulation tool?

It is not. Doing half a million deletes in one transaction will be dead slow (delete one by one) and EF is just not done for this. As you found out.

Nothing you can do here. Start using EF within design parameters or choose an alternative approach for this bulk operations. There are cases an ORM makes little sense.

Comment: FWIW EF 7 should have support for batch operations (although not necessarily in 7.0) https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015357-batch-cud-support

Comment: I didn't, I'm just learning the limitations through trial and error - someone did make a bulkInsert which actually inserts a million rows in a few seconds - so I thought just to continue on and try with removal aswell

Comment: Well, the bulk indsert works by bypassing EF core (I know, I do the same). But a 1 million row deletes is also a LOT more taxing on the server ;) SQL servers generally are more optimized for inserts and selects.

Comment: I don't agree that there is nothing you can do about this, EntityFramework.Extended library has found a way to offer bulk inserts / updates / deletes. Also why is your attitude so confrontational? The guy is asking a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul No, sorry. Extended Library is not using EF - it is bypassing thecomplete EF functionality. Yes, it works, but it is not "using EF". Jsut because someone writes and extension method for a EF DbContext does not make it "using EF". The bulk delete forexmaple is totally orthogonal to the loaded enties and does not update them. Not saying it is useless - it is a great approach - but the EF integration is window dressing to keep one "visible API".

Comment: @TomTom I am perfectly aware that it is not using "EF" as you put it, you do not need to explain that to me. However what it does do is share the same syntax as well as add a lot of convenience. Perhaps we interpreted the question differently, I assumed the user was looking for a way to do a bulk delete using a syntax that is familiar to him... Still, didn't need to be so confrontational, we are all learning dude. Cut some slack.

Comment: I agree that the sentiment in the post is a bit "confrontational" but don't shoot the messenger: EF is the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions.

1. Use a stored procedure or plain SQL
2. Move your DbContext to a narrower scope:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i += 1000)
   {
     using (var db = new DbContext())
     {
       var chunk = largeListOfAddress.Take(1000).Select(a => new Address { Id = a.Id });
       db.Address.RemoveRange(chunk);
       db.SaveChanges();
     }
   }
   ```

See [Rick Strahl's post on bulk inserts for more details](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/22/Entity-Framework-and-slow-bulk-INSERTs)